# Call BeanShell function from BeanShell Programs like PreProcessor, PostProcessor, Assertion, etc

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

**Pre-requisite:**

Inside JMeter bin folder, I have edited `BeanShellFunction.bshrc` file to add my function as follows

```
String getMyString()
{
    return "MyString";
}
```

I have enabled the `BeanShellFunction.bshrc` from `jmeter.properties` file as

> beanshell.function.init = BeanShellFunction.bshrc

When I use the following syntax to call function it works fine.

```
${__BeanShell(getMyString())}
```

It works fine for below case:
[image: BeanShell Function Call]

**Question:**

How can I call the same function from BeanShell Programs like PreProcessor, PostProcessor, Assertion, etc.?

**Analysis:**

I tried with following but no luck:

```
String myStr = getMyString();
```

[image: BeanShell Assertion]

It gives an error as:

> Assertion error: true
>   Assertion failure: false
>   Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``  String myStr = getMyString();  print("MyStr: "+myStr);'' : Typed variable declaration : Command not found: getMyString()

[image: BeanShell Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this SO post I found the solution: [Calling Jmeter Functions from BeanShell Assertion Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166543/calling-jmeter-functions-from-beanshell-assertion-script)

**Solution**
For each BeanShell Program type there are different `beanshell.*.init` properties defined in `bin/user.properties`:

> beanshell.function.init=BeanShellFunction.bshrc
>   beanshell.preprocessor.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc 
>   beanshell.postprocessor.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc 
>   beanshell.assertion.init=BeanShellFunction.bshrc

Hence the same function which needs to be called from any program(preprocessor, postprocessor, etc) we need to **copy the function** to every `.bshrc` file *OR* use **same `.bshrc` file** for every program init property.

**Syntax to use:**

You need use the same syntax used for sending URL parameter:

```
String myStr = "${__BeanShell(getMyString())}";
```

This automatically calls the beanshell method from defined `.bshrc` file.

[image: BeanShell Program]

**For Advance Scripting**
If your BeanShell function accepts a parameter:

```
String getMyString(String strParam)
{
    return "MyString: "+strParam;
}
```

And you want to pass a property as a parameter to the BeanShell function, you can use following syntax:

```
String myStr = "${__BeanShell(getMyString("${__P(param1)}"))}";
```

[image: BeanShell Advance]

Believe me it works and it does not give any syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   beanshell.function.init=BeanShellFunction.bshrc
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Once done you should be able to use it wherever required

   [image: JMeter Beanshell Custom Function]

Same approach applies to

- `beanshell.sampler.init`
- `beanshell.assertion.init`
- `beanshell.listener.init`
- etc.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: you don't understand my question, can you please elaborate more on your point number 3.? What is the syntax for using it in BeanShell Program?

Comment: 1. Put `${__BeanShell(getMyString())}` to "Parameters" section
2. Refer to it as `String str = Parameters;`